# JBrowserDriver takes more than a minute to initialize

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm using JBrowserDriver to take screenshots from some pages but when I create the driver variable it takes more than a minute (around 70 seconds).

```
  JBrowserDriver driver = new JBrowserDriver(Settings.builder().
  timezone(Timezone.AMERICA_NEWYORK).build());
```

I'm running JBrowserDriver directly from Maven when facing this problem

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.machinepublishers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jbrowserdriver</artifactId>
  <version>[0.12.0, 2.0)</version>
</dependency>
```

Any hints for finding the root cause of this, or common possible causes of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, but I found a solution. For default JBrowser uses **Tor Browser**. I set it to **Chrome Browser**.

```
WebDriver driver = new JBrowserDriver(Settings.builder().userAgent(UserAgent.CHROME).build());
```

Try it. In my case I reduced the time to less than 10 seconds. Good luck!

Comment: use headless chrome. do not use jbrowserdriver.